# How can I rotate an RectangleF at a specific degree using Graphics object?

Tags: c#, .net, rotation, transformation

I have tried this:

```
g.RotateTransform(degrees);
```

But nothing happens.I have one graphics object and one rectangle object witch im drawing using this method:

```
g.FillRectangle(new TextureBrush(Image.FromFile(@"D:\LOVE&LUA\Pictures\yellowWool.png")), rectangle);
```

And i need to rotate the rectangle somehow and draw it again.

Answer with code sample please and with a simple explanation.

EDIT: Here is the actual code I'm using:

```
        public void Draw(Graphics g,PointF location,Color clearColor)
    {
        rectangle.Location = location;
        g.Clear(clearColor);
        g.RotateTransform(10);
        //g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color), rectangle);
        g.FillRectangle(new TextureBrush(Image.FromFile(@"D:\LOVE&LUA\Pictures\yellowWool.png")), rectangle);
    }
```

Each frame I call this function and I'm using form's Paint event's `e.Graphics` object for the Graphics and i have a `timer` witch only calls `this.Refresh();`

EDIT 2: 
OK I have played a little with the transformations and `g.RotateTransform` rotates the whole cordinate system of the graphycs object and i need to rotate only the rectangle without changing the cordinate system

Comment: Are you calling both lines in this order? Could you show the entire code fragment (including things such as the actual number of degrees)

Comment: No TranslateTransform, that's trouble.  http://www.bobpowell.net/transformations.htm

Comment: @HansPassant - That is quite cryptic... care to explain?

Comment: @Erno - it rotates around the upper left corner by default.  Without moving the coordinate system with TT, the rectangle is rotated out of view.

Comment: @HansPassant - not when it is just 10 degrees, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a matrix with the `RotateAt` method to center the rotation around the rectangle:

```
using (Matrix m = new Matrix()) {
  m.RotateAt(10, new PointF(rectangle.Left + (rectangle.Width / 2),
                            rectangle.Top + (rectangle.Height / 2)));
  g.Transform = m;
  using (TextureBrush tb = new TextureBrush(Image.FromFile(@"D:\LOVE&LUA\Pictures\yellowWool.png"))
    g.FillRectangle(tb, rectangle);
  g.ResetTransform();
}
```

The `ResetTransform()` will turn the graphics back to normal processing after that.

Comment: When I use ResetTransform() would't the rotation reset back to normal too?

Comment: @Bosak Not for the one FillRectangle that was called.  This code basically says, start drawing with a rotation, draw stuff, then stop drawing with a rotation.  Hope that helps.