# Applying rotation to Graphics object

Tags: graphics

I have very little experience programming with graphics objects. I am currently tasked with exporting a document (.tiff image) with redacted annotations. The redacted annotation is just a black rectangle object. I am able to get the x coordinates, y coordinates, width and height properties through the .XMP data. There is also a property called rotatation. This is where I am getting stuck, applying the rotation.

So, imagine a document with a redaction on it blacking out the first paragraph. Then, using a tool in the editor the user rotates the document so that it is now laying on it's side. The client is able to render the redaction correctly because we are using the Atalasoft controls to get and display annotations. Now we have a web service that will go and retrieve that image with redactions. We are not able to use the Atalasoft controls in this service due to licensing issues so we just extract the .XMP data from the .tiff image and manually draw the redactions. The problem is, if the user rotates the document when the redaction is already on the document I am having a hard time getting the redaction to rotate correctly (due to my lack of knowledge on graphics programming). If I do not apply any rotation, the redaction is displayed where it was BEFORE the document had been rotated, thus redacting the wrong area of the document.

Here is what I have tried:

```
Dim rectangle As New Rectangle(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, width, height)
graphics.RotateTransform(rotation)
graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, rectangle)
```

When I do this, the redaction does not show up at all on the final document. I have read that I may need to call the following before applying the rotation:

```
graphics.TranslateTransform(x,y)
```

But I have no idea what I should be passing in as x and y. It seems like I just need to get the rotation to apply from the upper left corner of the rectangle, but I have yet to figure out a way to properly do this.

Thank you so much for any help or pushes in the right direction!

EDIT 1:

I have also tried this (taken from [How can I rotate an RectangleF at a specific degree using Graphics object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189383/how-can-i-rotate-an-rectanglef-at-a-specific-degree-using-graphics-object)).

```
Dim rectangle As New Rectangle(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, width, height)

Using rotationMatrix As New Matrix

    rotationMatrix.RotateAt(rotation, New PointF(rectangle.Left + (rectangle.Width / 2), rectangle.Top + (rectangle.Height / 2)))
    graphics.Transform = rotationMatrix
    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, rectangle)
    graphics.ResetTransform()

End Using
```

Which does rotate the rectangle, but it ends up in the wrong spot so it is not redacting the correct portion of the document. Once again, when I display the document without any rotation transform, it looks like the redaction simply needs to be rotated using the upper left corner as an axis but I'm not quite sure how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Here is how I am rotating a rectangle using the upper left-hand corner as the axis:

```
Dim rectangle As New Rectangle(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, width, height)

Using rotationMatrix As New Matrix

    rotationMatrix.RotateAt(rotation, New PointF(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top))
    graphics.Transform = rotationMatrix
    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, rectangle)
    graphics.ResetTransform()

End Using
```